# Why is the x position of the QML TabButton negative?

Tags: qt, qml

In QML, I'm using `TabButton` and I need its `x` value for some customization but when I'm using its `x` value it's not working correctly now consider the below QML code

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.14

Window {
    height: 768
    width: 432
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    TabBar {
        id: bar
        width: parent.width
        LayoutMirroring.enabled: false
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("Home")
            onClicked: console.log("Home: " + x)
        }
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("Discover")
            onClicked: console.log("Discover: " + x)
        }
        TabButton {
            id:activityButton
            text: qsTr("Activity")
            onClicked: console.log("Activity: " + x)
        }
    }

    StackLayout {
        width: parent.width
        currentIndex: bar.currentIndex
        Item {
            id: homeTab
        }
        Item {
            id: discoverTab
        }
        Item {
            id: activityTab
        }
    }
}
```

When I click on TabButtons output is like below

```
qml: Discover: -143.66666666666666
qml: Activity: 0.6666666666666856
qml: Home: -288
```

Can anyone explain to me why this value is not correct and it's negative?
And why the correct value is `(288 + x)`?

Comment: that's funny, I get the same result. Besides the issue, what do you want to do with `x`?

Comment: I want to use it for my custom style for Navigation Menu for now I'm using another approach but I was looking for the cause.

Comment: what is your qt version?

Comment: My Qt version is 5.15.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to the accepted answer it is not a bug.
[Qt documents](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-flickable.html#originX-prop) says

> originX : real
>
> originY : real
>
> These properties hold the origin of the content. This value always refers to the top-left position of the content regardless of layout direction.
>
> This is usually (0,0), however ListView and GridView may have an arbitrary origin due to delegate size variation, or item insertion/removal outside the visible region.

So you actually need to subtract originX from the x to get the correct result.
to access originX you could use ListView.view attached property here :

```
    TabButton {
        text: qsTr("Home")
        onClicked: console.log("Home: " + (x - ListView.view.originX))
    }
    TabButton {
        text: qsTr("Discover")
        onClicked: console.log("Discover: " + (x - ListView.view.originX))
    }
    TabButton { 
        text: qsTr("Activity")
        onClicked: console.log("Activity: " + (x - ListView.view.originX))
    }
```

Comment: You add `width:  implicitWidth*2.3`  to your answer :) original code in question didn't have `implicitWidth` i said that was bug because without changing code I just compile it with  `Qt 6.2.3` and it works correctly :)

Comment: I copied answer code instead of question code :))) sorry. yeah but with adding and removing items that problem occurs again.

Answer (score 3):

This is my result when I compile it with **Qt** `5.15.2` :

[image]

[image]

and This is my result when I compile it with **Qt** `6.2.3` :

[image]

[image]

**In Qt  `6.2.3` the Results are correct but I lost the theme that was in Qt `5.15.2`.look at the TabBar in both pictures.**

**So this is a bug in the version of Qt `5.15.2`  and they fixed it in Qt6.**

Now how can fix it in  Qt `5.15.2`, I add  `width: implicitWidth` in each `TabButton` and test it again:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.14

Window {
    height: 768
    width: 432
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    TabBar {
        id: bar
        width: parent.width
        LayoutMirroring.enabled: false
        TabButton {
            id:homeButton
            width:  implicitWidth*2.3
            text: qsTr("Home")
            onClicked: console.log("Home: " + x)
        }
        TabButton {
            id:discoverButton
            width:  implicitWidth*2.3
            text: qsTr("Discover")
            onClicked: console.log("Discover: " + x)
        }
        TabButton {
            id:activityButton
            width:  implicitWidth*2.3
            text: qsTr("Activity")
            onClicked: console.log("Activity: " + x)
        }
    }


    StackLayout {
        width: parent.width
        currentIndex: bar.currentIndex
        Item {
            id: homeTab
        }
        Item {
            id: discoverTab
        }
        Item {
            id: activityTab
        }
    }

}
```

and that bug was fixed I guess that happens because you said `width: parent.width` and it decides x value after setting layout.

[image]